# ListView content is on top of header

Tags: listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

When creating a sticky header on a `ListView` using the Composition API ([example](http://meanme.com/2017/07/11/sticky-header/)), the content of the ListView can go over the Header.

Normally, this kind of thing would be solved with `Canvas.ZIndex`, but this doesn't work as expected.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.Header>
        <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="1">
            <!--Some content-->
        </Grid>
     </ListView.Header>
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <!-- Some content -->  
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Real world example:
[image: Visual example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ZIndex` is relative to the other nodes at the same level, so you need to change the `ZIndex` directly on the `ListView.Header` from code behind. Setting it on any content *in* the Header will not work.

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
     <ListView.Header>
        <Grid>
            <!--Some content-->
        </Grid>
    </ListView.Header>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- Some content -->  
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
public ListViewExample()
{
    var headerPresenter = (UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((UIElement)listView.Header);
    var headerContainer = (UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(headerPresenter);
    Canvas.SetZIndex(headerContainer, 1);
}
```